# как сделать // TODO: в IntellijIdea для файлов .html?

Tags: intellij-idea

Я нашел очень полезным для себя использовать // TODO: в IntellijIdea
Это очень удобно (до этого просто вел блокнот). Но загвоздка в том, что список ToDo формируется только из комментариев в классах, но не в файлах html которые тоже используются в проекте ((( Может ToDo как-то настраивается чтобы на этот комментарий все файлы проверялись?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кроме ответа ниже еще один совет. Не пишите руками // для комментария. В некоторых языках программирования комментарии по разному объявляются. Например в php '//', в html '<!-- -->' и т.д. Используйте хоткеи. Для мака 'cmd + /', для винды и линукса: 'ctrl + /'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё работает так же, как обычно, только комментарий в *html* документе обозначается не двумя слэшами. Используйте такую конструкцию:

```
<!--TODO: fix it-->
```

---

Пример для ***Rider*** (работает на том же движке, что и ***IntelliJ IDEA***):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все получилось